# Is it ok to set [Parameter]s in OnInitialized()?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I write the code and the UX person then decides how to use it. This includes setting a date range for what is displayed on a page.

In my code behind I have:

```
[Parameter]
public int? Start { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public int? End { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // calculate the dates
    if (Start != null)
        StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(Start.Value);
    // 0 is end of today, so midnight tonight minus 1 second.
    if (End != null && (!ShowEndDate))
        EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(End.Value + 1).AddSeconds(-1);

    await InitializeEventData();
}
```

Now the UX person will want to play with different values for the Start/End (and a number of other settings). This is a page, not a component, so it can't be set with `<MyComponent Start="3"/>`.

Is the following an acceptable way to provide the UX person with a way to set the values? This is in the .razor file (obviously):

```
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Start = 0;
        End = 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is probably no, but I need to understand a bit more to be certain . Pages and components are the same thing.  Pages just have one of more routes set.  If this is a page, why have you defined `Start` and `End` as `Parameters`?  Who's setting them?  As your code is written you are overriding any values that are originally set.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis HH pointed out below I was approaching this all wrong.

Comment: He is spot on.  I just didn't deduce enough of your context correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a page, not a component,

In that case your UXer should be able alter a URL ending with `?start=1&end=5`

Comment: Ok, that was really stupid of me. Yep, need them all to be `[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "Start")]` thanks